# Is it possible to set different colours for different types of comments in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, comments

Is it possible to set one colour for `//` comments and another for `#` in PhpStorm IDE?

I would like to use `#` comments for short descriptions on how the code works or for indicating some sections in classes (like `# Accessors`, `# Calculations` etc followed by adequate methods) and `//` for temporary comments. For this it would be extremely helpful to have different colours.

I don't think this is possible with default PhpStorm setup (hope I am wrong), but maybe is there an plugin for such thing?

Comment: you should stick to one type of single-line comment, mixing it up like this can cause a pedantic developer's hair to fall out :)

Comment: @Fisher Based on your description ... you want to use certain comments as group separators (here are all "Accessor" methods, here "Calculations" etc). PhpStorm supports regions: will works as foldable region in actual code (so you can fold whole group at once) as well as will display such methods as a separate node in Structure Panel. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/ and https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/05/improved-structure-view-in-phpstorm-9/

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, thats quite cool feature, will give it a try for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible ... and existing ticket has "Backlog" state (maybe one day, low priority).

Watch this ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18806 (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Ticket that describes your reasoning [WI-38657](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38657) is marked as duplicate for more general ticket (see above).